# Reference old library from Asp.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add a vanilla class library (ClassLibrary1, built with .Net 4.6.1 although I have tried 4.5.1) to a ASP.NET 5 web project(1.0.0-rc1-update1, though I've tried 1.0.0-rc1-final too) where both are part of the same solution.

I tried the usual *add reference* from VS, which doesn't work. I get this:

[image]

I then tried using dnu wrap like this:

```
dnu wrap ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj
```

This generated the following project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "wrappedProject": "../../ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1.csproj",
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../ClassLibrary1/obj/{configuration}/ClassLibrary1.dll",
        "pdb": "../../ClassLibrary1/obj/{configuration}/ClassLibrary1.pdb"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then added this to the ASP.NET 5 project.json

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  }
```

When I restore the packages, I get this error

*NU1002 The dependency ClassLibrary1 1.0.0 in project WebApplication1 does not support framework DNX,Version=v4.5.1.*

I can't add the namespace or anything.

I then tried the more sensible approach of actually targeting net461

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { "dependencies": { "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*" } },
    "dnx451": { "dependencies": { } },
    "dnxcore50": { "dependencies": { } }
  }
```

On the surface it seems like this is working but it won't build the minute anything from ClassLibrary1 is referenced.

If I remove the dnx frameworks, it will build but it won't work when I try to debug it. I get this error message

```
The program '[9328] dnx.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[15060] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

I have even tried this and even went as far as hardcoding the paths but to no avail

```
"frameworks": {
    "net461": { "dependencies": { "ClassLibrary1": "1.0.0-*" } },
    "dnx451": {
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../ClassLibrary1/obj/{configuration}/ClassLibrary1.dll",
        "pdb": "../../ClassLibrary1/obj/{configuration}/ClassLibrary1.pdb"
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there a way of doing this?

I must be missing something...